# Reload Div calling php file without page reload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a div element which call other php file output by php tag

```
<div class="View"> <?php
echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/livefeed.php?site=" . $_GET["site"] . "&num=6");
?></div>
```

I want to reload this div element without reloading whole page. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is using ajax, html, jquery, and php to make the contents of the div reload every five seconds. You need two files: **index.php** and **livefeed.php**.

**index.php:**

```
<div class="View"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
            url: "livefeed.php?site=<?php echo $_GET["site"]; ?>&num=6",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){        
                $(".View").html(html);          

            },
        });
},5000);
</script>
```

Now every 5 seconds it will grab the contents from livefeed.php and put it in the div.

Comment: can i have summary.php instead of index.php

Comment: this works but captioned div show my website index.php page. but i want to use this code on summary.php page

Comment: you can use summary.php instead of index.php

Comment: @ParvinderSingh please upvote this and mark as correct answer if it helped you

Comment: besides i want to refresh content very smoothly by using fade in or fade out function. How to do this.

Comment: is there any to reload page without page reload with php only

Comment: @ParvinderSingh Yes but you still need to use AJAX and such, with different files loading the page

Comment: Can u provide me some more details

Comment: @ParvinderSingh I cannot do it here in the comments, create a new questions and link it here and I'll respond

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX. Since the question has a `jQuery` tag, here is the jQuery solution.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $(".View").load("sitename")
}, 20000)} //Every 20000 miliseconds (20 secs)
```

However, you will need to know the site name. You could inject it into the code but you would have to make sure you don't get a XSS (Cross-site-scripting) attack.

You should be able to securely pass all the data if you escape quotes and backslashes in the string. This is still quite dangerous, however.

I assume that the `site=...` shouldn't contain `"` or `\`. If so, you should remove these characters before placing them into the HTML.

```
<div class="View" data-update="<?php echo "http://example.com/livefeed.php?site=" . str_replace("\\", '', str_replace('"', '', $_GET["site"])) . '&num=6">';
    echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/livefeed.php?site=" . $_GET["site"] . "&num=6");
    ?></div>
```

And then you can do

```
setInterval(function(){
    $(".View").load($(".View").data("update"))
}, 20000)} //Every 20000 miliseconds (20 secs)
```

---

What we have done is removed dangerous characters like `"` and `\` and then made an AJAX request. Here is the full code.

```
<div class="View" data-update="<?php echo "http://example.com/livefeed.php?site=" . str_replace("\\", '', str_replace('"', '', $_GET["site"])) . '&num=6">';
    echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/livefeed.php?site=" . $_GET["site"] . "&num=6");
    ?></div>
<script>
    setInterval(function(){
        $(".View").load($(".View").data("update"))
    }, 20000)} //Every 20000 miliseconds (20 secs)
</script>
```

Comment: sir i am a basic programmer, can u explain with details

Comment: The answer below works, but is **very** dangerous. You need to make sure that ```\``` and `"` are filtered out of the URL before placing them into the JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, I have edited it. I cannot guarantee it is completely secure nor that it works.

Comment: i have tried above code. But the captioned div show example.com/index.php page

Comment: You can remove the quotes and backslashes, or replace them, or use the other answer but secure it with the methods I mentioned.